# Got a problem with a widget

Tags: widgets, customization

i am trying to build a widget that would display
a list of top authors on sidebar..

This is not my first widget but it is my second one 
so my apologies if i am way off..

The problem is that when i drag the widget into the side (in admin ofcourse)
and saves it apears no where..later when i check i see after refreshing the
widgets page it doesent apear to exist..

**here is my widget code:** -->
http://pastebin.com/Hf4xTUHG

i know it rather langthy but can anyone help / give an idea as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sticks if you don't include `id_base` in `$control_ops`, when you pass it to WP_Widget in the constructor.

Looking at the [core](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/wp/wp-includes/widgets.php.source.html#line76) code it looks as though `id_base` is actually the first arg to WP_widget and the `$control_ops` array should only carry 'width' and 'height' keys.

Comment: thank alot man!! you saved my.. Sorry to trouble but got any idea WHY THE TITLE ISN'T BEING SAVED ??

Comment: Got the title to work 2 - all is cool.. thanks for you help again :)

Comment: great. no problem :)